# How to take input from TextBox and use that input in game loop in a Windows Forms App?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a text based adventure game. In the game, there is a ListBox which displays text, and TextBox where user types the commands:

[image: Game Interface]

I put the game loop in the Game_Load method which makes a problem because it keeps checking the TextBox content at all times and since it's empty before the user gets a chance to type anything it returns null and crashes.

I've made a similar game as a Console app before with this code:

```
while(run) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("What is your next step?");
    var input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    if (input == Text.Language.Quit)
        run = false;
    else
        Actions.Instance.Execute(input.Split(" "));
}
```

And it worked fine. Now I'm struggling to convert this to Windows Forms, I don't know where to put which method to avoid this problem.

How do I make the game not ask for input before it is needed?

I tried making a GetText method and calling that instead of var input = ... but that didn't work either. I tried moving the while(run) out of the Form_Load, but then it doesn't run at all times like it should.

Comment: No need for loops in this platform (there's already one running under the hood, you don't want to interfere with it). It appears you have a TextBox for the User input and another Control that shows the associated *action*. Subscribe to the `KeyDown` event of the input TextBox, verify it's `Keys.Enter`, suppress this key press (`e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`) and evaluate the content of the `Text` property of the TextBox -- A GUI platform is mainly event-driven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want something that looks and behaves like a Console, but in a WinForms app, and this is a stylistic choice. *Otherwise there are better ways to prompt user for input in WinForms!*

Running a "game loop" similar to your console app is possible but requires special care. We say that WinForms is "event-driven" because the application has a message loop that listens for events like mouse clicks and key presses. But this means, for example, that this loop is going to get stuck waiting for keypresses because it's "blocking the UI thread" that *detects* those keypresses.

```
void BadGameLoop()
{
    while(run)  // Don't do this!
    { 
        // The `Form` becomes unresponsive i.e.
        // The app "freezes" and will have to be killed.
        string input = ReadLine();
        switch(input)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the `await` keyword used inside an `async` method will cause the method to return immediately, but then resume at this spot when "something happens":

```
async Task GoodGameLoop()
{
    while(run) 
    { 
        string input = await ReadLineAsync();
        switch(input)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard]

---

**Read a command asynchronously**

Block when the `ReadLineAsync()` is called.

```
    SemaphoreSlim awaiter = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private async Task<string> ReadLineAsync()
    {
        int charIndex = Console.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        int line = Console.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
        string textB4 = Console.Lines[line];
        // Instruct the semaphore to block until further notice.
        awaiter.Wait(0);
        // Return from this method immediately.
        await awaiter.WaitAsync();
        // Resume here when [Enter] key unblocks the semaphore.
        string input = 
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textB4) ?
            Console.Lines[line] :
            Console.Lines[line].Replace(textB4, string.Empty);
        return input;
    }
```

Unblock the semaphore when the [Enter] key is pressed.

```
    private void onConsoleKeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Call Wait(0) so there's something to release
            // in case the awaiter isn't currently awaiting!
            try { awaiter.Wait(0); }
            finally{ awaiter.Release(); }
        }
    }
```

[image: command interpreter]

---

**Asynchronous Game Loop Example**

Here's the code I used to test this answer:

```
enum GameState
{
    DisplayLogo,
    PromptName,
    Intro,
    Play,
}
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.KeyDown += onConsoleKeyDown;
        _ = execGameLoop();
    }
    private GameState GameState = GameState.DisplayLogo;
    private async Task execGameLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            switch (GameState)
            {
                case GameState.DisplayLogo:
                    Console.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10);
                    Console.Text =
@"
                           ---------------
            ---------------               0
____________               ---------------
0           ---------------               |
------------                                |
|               WELCOME TO GORK               |
 |                              ---------------
  |             ---------------                0
   |____________                 ---------------
   0             ---------------
    ------------
";
                    Console.Select(Console.Text.Length, 0);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    GameState= GameState.PromptName;
                    continue;
                case GameState.PromptName:
                    Console.AppendText(@"
What is your name hero? ");
                    break;
                case GameState.Intro:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.AppendText(@"
OK let's PLAY!

Here are the rules:
#1 Don't cheat, unless winning requires it.
#2 Never forget rule #1.

For a list of commands, type 'help'.
Press Enter to continue.
"
                    );
                    break;
                case GameState.Play:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.AppendText(@"
Enter command: "
                        );
                    break;
            }
            string input = await ReadLineAsync();
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                if(GameState.Equals(GameState.Intro))
                {
                    GameState = GameState.Play;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (GameState)
                {
                    case GameState.PromptName:
                        Console.AppendText($"Welcome {input} to this adventure!" + Environment.NewLine);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                        {
                            Console.AppendText(">");
                            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)).Wait();
                        }
                        GameState= GameState.Intro;
                        break;
                    case GameState.Intro:
                        GameState= GameState.Play;
                        break;
                    case GameState.Play:
                        Console.AppendText($"You entered: {input}" + Environment.NewLine);
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
        // ReadLineAsync method ...
        // onConsoleKeyDown method ...
    }
}
```